# Disallow exponential value for long numbers in <f:convertNumber> 

Tags: java, jsf

Within this tag `<f:convertNumber>` for a long number I want to allow only whole number instead of exponential value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go for [custom converter](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)